# Getting started: combinatorial optimization for computer scientists

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, approximation-algorithms, global-optimization

I have a background in computer science and I am starting to work on some problems those are basically combinatorial optimization problems.

I have good knowleges of graphs, *-flow algorithms and so on and I took some courses about operations research and similar stuff.

I am looking for one (or two) book to get a uniform and semi-complete view on the topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the short version, [Combinatorial Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486402584) by Papadimitriou and Stieglitz is a good introduction, and at $12, you can't really go wrong.

For the in-depth version, [Combinatorial Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540443894) by Schrijver is pretty encyclopedic.

Comment: You accidentally linked twice to the book by Papadimitriou and Stieglitz.

Comment: The second one is impressive.

Answer (score 2):

Operative research -> operations research. A great reference is:

Introduction To Operations Research (IBM) [Hardcover]
Frederick S. Hillier (Author), Gerald J. Lieberman (Author)

Comment: Thank you but I guess there is a gap between OR and combinatorial optimization. Isn't there?

Comment: Well, if you know CS, you know the other part of combinatorial optimization (as you say yourself, network flows, etc). So, the OR is the part you are missing.